Packing tiny open sets into a large open set
The questions
Let $n$ be a positive integer, let $\lambda$ be the Lebesgue measure of $\mathbb R^n$, let $B$ and $U$ be two open subsets of $\mathbb R^n$ such that $B$ is bounded, $\lambda(B)=1$, and $0<\lambda(U)<\infty$. For $s\in\mathbb R_{>0}$ and $v\in\mathbb R^n$ define $g_{s,v}:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n$ by $g_{s,v}(x)=sx+v$, and set
$$
\mathcal B_s=\{g_{s,v}(B)\ |\ v\in\mathbb R^n\}.
$$
Let $k$ be a positive integer. An open subset $C$ of $U$ will be called a $k$-packing in $U$ if there is a $(k+1)$-tuple $(s,C_1,\ldots,C_k)$ such that
$\bullet$ $s\in\mathbb R_{>0}$,
$\bullet$ the $C_i$ are disjoint members of $\mathcal B_s$,
$\bullet$ we have $C=C_1\cup\cdots\cup C_k$.
For each such $k$-packing we set
$$
d(C):=\frac{\lambda(C)}{\lambda(U)}=\frac{ks^n}{\lambda(U)}\ . 
$$
This is a positive real number $\le1$, which we call the density of $C$. For each $k$ we denote by $d_k$ the supremum of the densities of the various $k$-packings in $U$. (Note that, for each $k$, there are infinitely many $k$-packings in $U$.)
QUESTION 1. Do the $d_k$ tend to a positive limit $d(n,B,U)$?
QUESTION 2. Does $d(n,B,U)$, when it exists, depend only on $n$ and $B$?
Comments
If $n=2$, the open sets $B$ and $U$ are respectively an open disk (of area $1$) and a square, then $d(2,B,U)$ exists and is equal to $\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt3}$. This follows from a claim on p. 109 of the book:
Croft HT, Falconer K, Guy RK. Unsolved problems in geometry: unsolved problems in intuitive mathematics. Springer Science and Business Media; 2012 Dec. 6.
Here are two links containing a lot of pieces of information and references:
The Wikipedia entry Packing problems.
The page Packomania of Eckehard Specht.
Two partial results
By open cube of side length $s>0$ we mean a cartesian product of $n$ open intervals of length $s$. Here are two very partial results:
PROPOSITION 1. If $B$ is an open cube, then $d_k$ tends to $1$.
PROPOSITION 2. In the general case we have $\liminf_{k\to\infty}d_k>0$.
Proof of Proposition 1
Note that $B$ has side length $1$, and that $\mathcal B_s$ is the set of all open cubes of side length $s$. Let $\mathcal U$ be the set of all nonempty open subsets of $\mathbb R^n$ of finite measure, and let $\mathcal D$ be the set of all those $U$ in $\mathcal U$ such that there is a sequence $(C_k)_{k>0}$ where, for each $k$, the set $C_k$ is a $k$-packing in $U$, and $\lim_{k\to\infty}\lambda(C_k)=\lambda(U)$. It suffices to show $\mathcal U=\mathcal D$.
The main ingredient will be Lemma 1.2.11 in Terrence Tao's book An Introduction to Measure Theory which implies that there is an at most countable set of disjoint open cubes contained in $U$ whose union has measure $\lambda(U)$.
In view of Tao's Lemma it suffices to prove:
(a) the open cubes are in $\mathcal D$,
(b) the finite unions of disjoint open cubes are in $\mathcal D$,
(c) if $U\in\mathcal U$ is the union of an increasing sequence $U_1, U_2,\ldots$ of members of $\mathcal D$, then $U\in\mathcal D$.
(d) If $V\subset U$ with $V\in\mathcal D$, $U\in\mathcal U$ and $\lambda(V)=\lambda(U)$, then $U\in\mathcal D$.
Note that (d) is immediate.
Proof of (a). Let $U\subset\mathbb R^n$ be an open cube of side length $s$. In particular $\lambda(U)=s^n$. Let $k>0$, set $m:=\lceil k^{1/n}\rceil$ and $t:=\frac sm\,$. (Note that $m$ and $t$ depend on $k$.) We can pack $m^n$ open cubes of side length $t$ into $U$. A fortiori we can pack $k$ open cubes $U_{k1},\ldots,U_{kk}$ of side length $t$ into $U$. Let $U_k$ be the $k$-packing $U_{k1}\cup\cdots\cup U_{kk}$ in $U$. We have
$$
\lambda(U_k)=kt^n=s^n\frac k{m^n}=s^n\left(\frac{k^{1/n}}{\lceil k^{1/n}\rceil}\right)^n,
$$
and thus $\lim_{k\to\infty}\lambda(U_k)=s^n=\lambda(U)$, that is, $U\in\mathcal D$. $\square$
Proof of (b). Let $U\subset\mathbb R^n$ be the union of $p$ disjoint open cubes $U_1,\ldots,U_p$. Let $s_i$ be the side length of $U_i$. In particular $\lambda(U_i)=s_i^n$. We can assume $\lambda(U)=\sum s_i^n=1$. Let $k>0$, set $k_i:=\lceil ks_i^n\rceil$. We get $ks_i^n\le k_i$ and thus $k\le\sum k_i$. Set
$$
m_i:=\lceil k_i^{1/n}\rceil,\quad t_i:=\frac {s_i}{m_i},\quad t:=\min_it_i
$$
and note that $m_i,t_i$ and $t$ depend on $k$.
We saw that we can pack $k_i$ open cubes of side length $t_i$ into $U_i$. A fortiori we can pack $k_i$ open cubes of side length $t$ into $U_i$. Hence, we can pack $\sum k_i$ open cubes of side length $t$ into $U$. A fortiori we can pack $k$ open cubes of side length $t$ into $U$.
It suffices to show $\lim_{k\to\infty}kt^n=1$. It even suffices to show $\lim_{k\to\infty}kt_i^n=1$ for all $i$. We have
$$
kt_i^n=\frac{ks_i^n}{k_i}\,\frac{k_it_i^n}{s_i^n}=\frac{ks_i^n}{\lceil ks_i^n\rceil}\ \frac{k_it_i^n}{s_i^n}\ .
$$
Since $\lim_{k\to\infty}k_it_i^n=s_i^n$ by the proof of (a), we get $\lim_{k\to\infty}kt_i^n=1$, as required. $\square$
Proof of (c). Let $U=U_1\cup U_2\cup\cdots$ with $U_i\in\mathcal D$ for all $i$ and $U_1\subset U_2\subset\cdots$ We can assume $\lambda(U)=1$. We must show $U\in\mathcal D$. Set $a_j:=\lambda(U_j)$. We have in particular $0<a_j\le a_{j+1}\le1$ and $\lim_{j\to\infty}a_j=1$. For each $j$ there is a sequence $(C_{jk})_{k>0}$ where each $C_{jk}$ is a $k$-packing of $U_j$ and, setting $a_{jk}:=\lambda(C_{jk})$, we get $0<a_{jk}\le a_j\le1$ and $\lim_{k\to\infty}a_{jk}=a_j$. We can assume $a_{jk}\le a_{j+1,k}$ for all $j,k$.
It suffices to show $\lim_{k\to\infty}a_{kk}=1$.
Let $\varepsilon$ be positive. There is a $j_0$ such that $a_{j_0}>1-\varepsilon$. There is a $k_0$ such that $k\ge k_0$ implies $a_{j_0k}>a_{j_0}-\varepsilon$. We can assume $k_0\ge j_0$. For $k\ge k_0$ we get
$$
a_{kk}\ge a_{j_0k}>a_{j_0}-\varepsilon>1-\varepsilon-\varepsilon=1-2\varepsilon.
$$
This completes the proof. $\square$
Proof of Proposition 2
Let the setting of Questions $1$ and $2$ be in force. We must show $\liminf_{k\to\infty}d_k>0$. Let $B'$ be the set denoted by $B$ in Proposition 1, that is, $B'$ is an open cube in $\mathbb R^n$ of side length $1$. Let also $\mathcal B'_s$ be the set denoted by $\mathcal B_s$ in the proof of Proposition 1, that is, $\mathcal B'_s$ is the set of all open cubes in $\mathbb R^n$ of side length $s$. We call $(k,\mathcal B)$-packing what was called $k$-packing at the beginning of the post, and define the notion of $(k,\mathcal B')$-packing in the obvious way.
Let $U$ be an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$ with $0<\lambda(U)<\infty$. We can assume $\lambda(U)=1$. The proof of Proposition 1 shows that there is a sequence $(C'_k)_{k>0}$ such that
$\bullet$ each $C'_k$ is a $(k,\mathcal B')$-packing $C'_k=C'_{k1}\cup\cdots\cup C'_{kk}$ in $U$ with $C'_{ki}\in\mathcal B'_{s_k}$ (in particular $\lambda(C'_k)=ks_k^n$),
$\bullet$ we have $\lim_{k\to\infty}ks_k^n=1$.
Since $B$ is bounded and has measure $1$, it is contained in some open cube $D$ of side length $t\ge1$, i.e. $D\in\mathcal B'_t$. Hence, each open cube of side length $u$ contains some member of $\mathcal B_{u/t}$. In particular, for each $(k,i)$ with $1\le i\le k>0$ the open cube $C'_{ki}$ (which has side length $s_k$) contains some $C_{ki}\in\mathcal B_{s_k/t}$, of measure $(s_k/t)^n$, and $C_k:=C_{k1}\cup\cdots\cup C_{kk}$ is a $(k,\mathcal B)$-packing in $U$ of measure $ks_k^n/t^n$. This implies $d_k\ge ks_k^n/t^n$, and thus
$$
\liminf_{k\to\infty}d_k\ge\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{ks_k^n}{t^n}=\frac1{t^n}>0.\ \square
$$

are you aware of the hausdorff dimension?

I can't say I know this notion. I took a quick look at the Wikipedia entry, but I don't see how this notion is related to my questions. Thanks in advance for your help!
